# What is the system-wide limit on simultaneous Mach Port allocations?

Tags: macos

I'm occasionally experiencing various processes crashing with the message `__THE_SYSTEM_HAS_NO_PORT_SETS_AVAILABLE__` in the backtrace.  I suspect this might be related to one long-running process allocating and leaking Mach Ports.

Is there a system-wide limit on how many Mach Ports can be allocated, and if so, how do I find out what that limit is?